# Interactive Graphics, 60fps, Human Perception

Tags: graphics

### Short Question

If my application is already rendering at 60fps, is there any additional benefit (from perspective of human perception) to render additional frames on state changes?

### Long question

I'm writing an interactive application in OpenGL, something like:

```
while(true) {
  render a frame;
  sleep right amount of time to hit 60fps
}
```

Now, in the MVC model, I would fire off a repaint on every state changes.

My question:

Given that I'm already rendering at 60fps from the model, is there any benefit to fire off a new repaint at every state change? Can humans actually perceive the slight difference in 33 milliseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they can, especially elite FPS gamers. You could set up a fixed time step system or some similar system to render as fast as possible and use interpolation during your extra frames to smooth animation. This can definitely make a difference, but then again time-resources-cost, maybe you have no need to have super smooth rendering.